# How do we calculate $P(X_5 = 2 \mid X_3 = 0, X_1 = 1)$?

Tags: markov-chains, transition-matrix

I have the following problem:

> Bob is a salesman. Each week, Bob will either make no money, make a small amount of money, or make a large amount of money. And if Bob makes money, he will either make \$100 (small amount) or \$1000 (large amount). For any given week, if Bob doesn't make any money in the previous week, then the probability that he will make a small amount of money is 0.6, and the probability that he will make a large amount of money is 0.3. For a week where he made a small amount of money in the previous week, the probability of making a small amount of money is 0.4 and the probability of making a large amount of money is 0.2. If Bob made a large amount of money in the previous week, then this week he will make a small amount of money with probability 0.3, and no money with probability 0.7. Let this be a Markov chain $(X_n, n \ge 0)$ with state space $\{0, 1, 2 \}$, where making no money is $0$, making a small amount of money is $1$, and making a large amount of money is $2$.

I calculated the transition matrix as

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0.1 & 0.6 & 0.3 \\ 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.2 \\ 0.7 & 0.3 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

I am trying to calculate $P(X_5 = 2 \mid X_3 = 0, X_1 = 1)$. The problem here is that we are not given $X_4$, so the jump from $X_3$ to $X_5$ is actually two jumps, so I don't understand how we proceed. I've been searching for resources that explain this, but all of the examples I could find were for probabilities that were conditioned on something that was only 1 step in the past. How do we calculate $P(X_5 = 2 \mid X_3 = 0, X_1 = 1)$?

---

### EDIT:

I'm now trying to work backwards. If we start with $X_3 = 0$, then we have with probability $0.1$ that $X_4 = 0$, $0.6$ that $X_4 = 1$, and $0.3$ that $X_4 = 2$. Now, since we know that $X_5 = 2$, we know that the relevant probabilities are that $X_4 = 0$ with $0.3$, $X_4 = 1$ with $0.2$, and $X_4 = 2$ with $0$. I'm not sure if this is on the right track.

Comment: I think you will have to go from $X_3 = 0$ to three states in $X_4$ and then from each state in $X_4$ to $X_5 = 2$

Comment: @MathLover Any chance you could please show me? I'm honestly so confused by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$P(X_5 = 2 \mid X_3 = 0, X_1 = 1) = \sum_{n=0}^2P(X_5 = 2 \mid X_4 = n)P(X_4=n\mid X_3=0)$$

Comment: Hi Martund. I've tried working backwards. If we start with $X_3 = 0$, then we have with probability $0.1$ that $X_4 = 0$, $0.6$ that $X_4 = 1$, and $0.3$ that $X_4 = 2$. Now, since we know that $X_5 = 2$, we know that the relevant probabilities are that $X_4 = 0$ with $0.3$, $X_4 = 1$ with $0.2$, and $X_4 = 2$ with $0$. Not sure if this is on the right track.

Comment: No @ThePointer, I am not working backwards. I am just using total probability theorem along with definition of Markov Chain (and therefore dropping $X_1$ altogether and $X_3=0$ from the given conditions in the first term on the RHS). I am working forwards by making cases, in a nutshell.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks. I've summed out the values as in your answer. Do we now just calculate the 4-step transition matrix $PPPP = P^4$ and the 3-step transition matrix $PPP = P^3$ and use the probability values in the matrices to calculate the summation on the RHS?

Comment: @ThePointer, I don't see why do you need to calculate powers of transition matrix in order to calculate this sum. All the probabilities in RHS are part of $P$ itself, the one step transition matrix.

Comment: And btw, we are calculating the probability of going to $2$ from state $0$ in two steps, so we are essentially calculating the corresponding entry in $P^2$.